# How to connect IPC and RPC to transact fake ethers?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, private-blockchain, testrpc

I have setup 2 nodes, 1 on testRPC and the other on geth(using cmd and mist).

How to sync both the nodes so that I can write a crowdfunding smartcontract for the accounts in both the private nodes to contribute?

Is it possible to connect by knowing RPC path and piping with IPC path using geth console?

Please explain how and where to get RPC path and also the method of piping required.

Answer (score 1):

There are two popular ways you can do:

Connecting to testnet/mainnet:

1. Use geth command with mode to sync Eth block chain. You no need to trust any 3rd party vendor. Use `fast` mode to download database is fast and less space when compare to full mode. `--syncmode "fast"`. I'll recommend this process.

> geth [config] --testnet  --syncmode "full"

After run above command you will find HTTP endpoint opened: **http://127.0.0.1:8545** This is RPC mode, ip. Using this ip you can able to connect.

2. Connecting to provider, If you don't have time to sync and space. Then you can connect with dev's are trying to connect. You need to create an account infura for getting Infura_Access_Token. Account creation in Infura is free.

*For local network, any way you will use geth client with your own genesis.json.*

For more details, refer below link:

[Integration guide for infura provider with truffle](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider)

[infura signup](https://infura.io/signup)

[How to step multiple networks in local system](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38500/can-we-create-multiple-private-blockchains-in-a-single-computer/38519#38519)

[Requesting Test Ethers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10010/how-to-get-testnet-ether)

Comment: @Pavan Ramesh If you feel ans is relevant and given some direction to your qus. Can you please mark as solved.